# Python: Printing sub elements in a list to a CSV

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-structures

I have a list of gps coordinates. Below is the format of these coordinates. This is Route 0, if you will, and it represents the locations visited by a driver. He starts at ('24.957055', ' -8.740156'), goes to ('34.956915136264', ' -10.753690062122') and returns to ('24.957055', ' -8.740156').

```
[[('24.957055', ' -8.740156'),
('34.956915136264', ' -10.753690062122'),
('24.957055', ' -8.740156')],...]
```

I want to create a data structure where each of the coordinates are categorised based on whether they are a Starting Point, an End Point or just an Intermediary Point.

Note: start point, end point = the same ie the driver always returns to base.

Desired output for Route 0:

```
Start, way_point_1, End
('24.957055', ' -8.740156'), ('34.956915136264', ' -10.753690062122'), ('24.957055', ' -8.740156')
```

The list of coordinates I have is much longer and I want to be able to loop through the full list and identify whether a coordinate is a Start, End or Intermediary Point.

Edit: Some of these Route will have more than 1 Intermediary Point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be simple enough, assuming I understand your question. Let's assume this list:

```
route0 = [[('24.957055', ' -8.740156'),
('34.956915136264', ' -10.753690062122'),
('36.956915136264', ' -6.753690062122'),
('66.956915136264', ' -12.753690062122'),
('24.957055', ' -8.740156')], [('48.957055', ' -16.740156'),
('68.956915136264', ' -20.753690062122'),
('48.957055', ' -16.740156')]]
```

all you need is a simple for loop:

```
for i in range(len(route0)):
    print(f'List Element: {i}\nstart: {route0[i][0]}\nEnd: {route0[i][-1]}\nIntermediary: {route0[i][1:-1]}\n')
```

Output:

```
List Element: 0
start: ('24.957055', ' -8.740156')
End: ('24.957055', ' -8.740156')
Intermediary: [('34.956915136264', ' -10.753690062122'), ('36.956915136264', ' -6.753690062122'), ('66.956915136264', ' -12.753690062122')]

List Element: 1
start: ('48.957055', ' -16.740156')
End: ('48.957055', ' -16.740156')
Intermediary: [('68.956915136264', ' -20.753690062122')]
```

Not matter what you want to do the general idea is the same:

```
route0[0][0] # looks at the first list and takes the first element
route0[0][-1] # looks at the first list and takes the last element
route0[0][1:-1] # looks at the first list and takes all the middle elements
```

To csv using pandas:

```
data = []

for i in range(len(route0)):
    s = route0[i][0]
    m = str(route0[i][1:-1]).replace('[','').replace(']','')
    e = route0[i][-1]
    data.append([s,m,e])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Start', 'Intermediary', 'End'])
df.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

to csv using CSV:

```
import csv

data = []

for i in range(len(route0)):
    s = route0[i][0]
    m = str(route0[i][1:-1]).replace('[','').replace(']','') #route0[i][1:-1]
    e = route0[i][-1]
    data.append([s,m,e])

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    headers = ['Start', 'Intermediary', 'End']
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Thanks a million. The f strings were of huge help to me here. I am discovering the world of data analysis and this was a great help to me. Would I be right in saying that I am dealing with a list within a list or "a list of lists"?